# How to add different headers for different build flavors using Retrofit

Tags: retrofit, retrofit2

Im new to retrofit and this question might be trivial. Here is a simple api interface

```
 public interface ApiRetrofitService {
    @GET("territories/url")
    @Headers({"Token: XXXXX"})
    public Call<List<Territory>> getTerritories();
    @GET("territories/url/current")
    @Headers({"Token: XXXXX"})
    public Call<Territory> getCurrentTerritory();
 }
```

I want to load the Headers from a static resource file, to keep it simple lets say I want to have the headers values stored in strings.xml in a `<string name="token">XXXXX</string>`.  Is there a way that i can add values from the strings.xml in the ApiRetrofitService header. I'm hopping for something like this:

```
    public interface ApiRetrofitService {
    @GET("territories/url")
    @Headers({"Token:" + R.strings.token})
    public Call<List<Territory>> getTerritories();
    @GET("territories/url/current")
    @Headers({"Token:" + R.strings.token})
    public Call<Territory> getCurrentTerritory();
}
```

And in general how do i solve the issue where i need to add different headers for differend build flavors? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's too late but it may help others.

You can use the dynamic header like

```
    @GET("territories/url/current")
public Call<Territory> getCurrentTerritory(@Header("Token") String token);
```

and when you call get method

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
  //call getCurrentTerritory(//debug string token)
}else{
  //call getCurrentTerritory(//production string token)
}
```